# Row Editing in the grid doesn't work in first click

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control which contains a grid and three buttons for add,edit and delete.
I have placed this user control on an asp.net page.
I have OnClick events for these buttons.
When i click on add and delete buttons it's working fine but when i click on edit button,the onclick event of edit button is fired but the row in the grid doesn't appear in the edit mode, i have to click two times.
I don't know where is the problem.The onclick event handler for edit button is as follows:

```
protected void btnEditBankAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            grdBankAccounts.EditIndex = grdBankAccounts.SelectedIndex;
            grdBankAccounts.RowSelectingEnabled = false;

        }
```

Anyone please help.

my user control has a method which binds the grid to the data source, it's as follows

```
public void SetSupplierData(SupplierType Supplier)
        {
            if (Supplier != null)
            {
                    ViewState["SupplierID"] = Supplier.SupplierId;
                    grdBankAccounts.DataSource = Supplier.BankAccounts;
                    grdBankAccounts.DataBind();
                    Session["BankAccounts"] = Supplier.BankAccounts;
         }
      }
```

the SetSupplierData method is called from the page where i have my user control.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this "in-place editing" in grids to work, I typically have to data-bind twice:

- once in the OnInit or OnLoad method so that the button click event handlers have the data available to work on
- in the OnPreRender method again to show the new values / new state (editing or not)

Marc

Comment: i have no idea why asp.net needs to databind twice but darn me this worked! Thanks a lot.